I need to write complex-value neural network in tensorflow but I get an error
I have complex input to into the neural network, and I also need the neural network to have complex weights, but when writing the code, I get the error as below:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-21-99efde09531b> in <cell line: 20>()
     18 
     19 # Instantiate the model with the corrected input parameter
---> 20 model = get_complex_model((10,))
     21 
     22 # Compile the model

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/activations/__init__.py in get(identifier)
    102     if callable(obj):
    103         return obj
--> 104     raise ValueError(
    105         f"Could not interpret activation function identifier: {identifier}"
    106     )

ValueError: Could not interpret activation function identifier: cart_relu

I also tried to use the standard activation function relu instead of cart_relu, but it also gives an error. Below is the code I use:
import numpy as np
from cvnn.layers import ComplexDense, ComplexInput
import tensorflow as tf


data = np.random.rand(1000, 10) + 1j * np.random.rand(1000, 10) # Generate synthetic complex-valued data
labels = (np.abs(data).sum(axis=1) > 5).astype(int)

def get_complex_model(input_shape):
    # Ensure that the shape argument is provided correctly to ComplexInput
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
    x = ComplexDense(10, activation='cart_relu')(inputs)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
    return model

# Instantiate the model with the corrected input parameter
model = get_complex_model((10,))


def tensorflow_model():
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf
    from cvnn.layers import ComplexDense, ComplexInput

    data = np.random.rand(1000, 10) + 1j * np.random.rand(1000, 10)
    labels = (np.abs(data).sum(axis=1) > 5).astype(int)

    def get_complex_model(input_shape):
        model_ = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        model_.add(ComplexInput(input_shape=input_shape))
        model_.add(ComplexDense(50, activation='cart_relu'))
        model_.add(ComplexDense(1, activation='convert_to_real_with_abs'))
        return model_

    model = get_complex_model((10,))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

    test_data = np.random.rand(200, 10) + 1j * np.random.rand(200, 10)
    test_labels = (np.abs(test_data).sum(axis=1) > 5).astype(int)

    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)
    print(f'Test accuracy: {test_acc}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tensorflow_model()

Output: Test accuracy: 1.0
Environment:

python==3.11.1
cvnn==2.0
tensorflow==2.15.0
tf_keras==2.15.1
tensorflow-probability[tf]==0.23.0
dm-tree==0.1.8

Please note that cvnn is experimental and not maintained, so it might not work with newer versions of Tensorflow. See Invalid dtype: complex64 with TF 2.16
